# How to update email with BAPI_USER_CHANGE in pyrfc?

Tags: python, saprfc, bapi, sap-basis, pyrfc

I was able to write the code to get the details from SAP thru BAPI_USER_GET_DETAIL, here is attached code to get the email from SAP backend:

```
import pyrfc
from pyrfc import Connection
setup= pyrfc.Connection(user=X , passwd=Y , mshost=Z , sysid=A , client=B , msserv= C , group=D )
result=setup.call(BAPI_USER_GET_DETAIL, USERNAME=abc)
print (result['ADDRESS']['E_MAIL'])
```

Expected Result: **abc@xyz.com**

I am in need to update email address for particular user in SAP, after researching found that by using `BAPI_USER_CHANGE` we can update new mail address but tried many times with no luck!

Can anyone please help in getting the correct syntax to run `BAPI_USER_CHANGE` in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your get BAPI is also a bit of incorrect, maybe on old versions of PyRFC it worked but now pyrfc module has `Connection` object, not `connection` and your code throws compilation error. It should be as follows:

```
import pyrfc
from pyrfc import Connection
RIS=pyrfc.Connection(user='USER', passwd='pw', ashost='hostey.com', sysid='KEK', sysnr='00', client='200', lang='EN', trace='3')
result=RIS.call("BAPI_USER_GET_DETAIL", USERNAME='MUELLER')
print(result['ADDRESS']['FULLNAME'])
```

Secondly, change BAPI is called the same as get BAPI, for me this code worked

```
ADDR = { "E_MAIL": 'wazawaza@mail.com'}
ADDX = { "E_MAIL": 'X'}
changed=RIS.call("BAPI_USER_CHANGE", USERNAME='MUELLER', ADDRESS=ADDR, ADDRESSX=ADDX)
print(changed["RETURN"])
```

it should show you smth like this output if executed correctly

> [{'TYPE': 'S', 'ID': '01', 'NUMBER': '039', 'MESSAGE': **'User MUELLER has changed'**, 'LOG_NO': '', 'LOG_MSG_NO': '000000', 'MESSAGE_V1': 'MUELLER', 'MESSAGE_V2': '', 'MESSAGE_V3': '', 'MESSAGE_V4': '', 'PARAMETER': '', 'ROW': 0, 'FIELD': 'BNAME', 'SYSTEM': 'T90CLNT090'}]

Weirdly new email does **not** showed neither with BAPI call nor in SE37, but perfectly showed in SU01.

[image]

I thinks this is because of the long char field in BAPI structure which prevents it from showing correctly. Maybe this was the reason why you considered your call unsuccessful?

Comment: Thanks @Suncatcher for your update, I was somehow able to get my code work like the way you said but getting this error in return:

"You are not authorized to change users in group" although I am passing only one user in my code. Any thoughts regarding this ?

Comment: Simple authorization issue, it has nothing to do with mass changes. You have no rights to group in which user resides. You need authorization S_USER_GRP with ACTVT = 02.

Answer (score 0):

For any "Update BAPI" you need to call BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT right after your BAPI call in order to actually commit the changes to the database.

Make sure the BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT is executed on the same "connection", because it needs to run in the same backend user session.

Comment: Thanks @Lanzelot for the update, I tried it but it did not work either ..